# How to check if a column in dataFrame is of StructType

Tags: scala, dataframe, match, apache-spark-sql

I want to know if a column in DataFrame is of StructType. I have the schema of DataFrame. I am trying to use the following code

```
df.schema.apply(1) match {
  case StringType => // Do Something
  case ? => // How to check if 1st column is of StructType
}
```

For example, Consider this case:

```
val personStructType =
  StructType(
    StructField("name", StringType, nullable = true, metadata = new MetadataBuilder().putBoolean("isPrimary", false).build) ::
    StructField("age", IntegerType, nullable = true, metadata = new MetadataBuilder().putBoolean("isPrimary", false).build) ::
    StructField("gender", StringType, nullable = true, metadata = new MetadataBuilder().putBoolean("isPrimary", false).build) ::
    Nil
  )

val idStructType =
  StructType(
    StructField("domain", StringType, nullable = true, metadata = new MetadataBuilder().putBoolean("isPrimary", false).build) ::
    StructField("id", StringType, nullable = true, metadata = new MetadataBuilder().putBoolean("isPrimary", false).build) ::
    Nil
  )

val schema =
  StructType(
    StructField("a", StringType, nullable = true, new MetadataBuilder().putBoolean("isPrimary", true).build) ::
    StructField("person", personStructType, nullable = true, metadata = new MetadataBuilder().putBoolean("isPrimary", false).build) ::
    StructField("identifier", idStructType, nullable = true, metadata = new MetadataBuilder().putBoolean("isPrimary", false).build) ::
    Nil
  )

val a0 = schema.apply(0).dataType
a0 == StringType // Result is true

val a1 = schema.apply(1).dataType
a1 == StructType // Result is false
```

Because a1 is `StructType(StructField(name,StringType,true), StructField(age,IntegerType,true), StructField(gender,StringType,true))`

How do I know if a1 is of StructType ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you write `a1 == StructType` or `case StructType`, you are comparing with the *value* called `StructType`, which is the companion object of *type* `StructType`.

You need to match against the type instead: `case struct: StructType` (or `case StructType(fields)`), just like you write `case x: String` and not `case String`.

Comment: Thanks @Alexey Matching with `case st: StructType` helped